# List awaiting TPL tasks from a dump file?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library

If I have a dump with deadlock caused by circular await, non-pumping UI thread or whatever else. Note that none of them are active, e.g. there's no thread in the process that has something useful in it's call stack.

Is there a way to get list of those tasks? The problem looks not unique and it surprises me somewhat I cannot find anything useful by googling (except [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891052.aspx) article, which doesn't have general solution either).

P.S. Yes, I know I can track it with my own TaskScheduler or TPL ETW events. And most probably given enough patience I can dig it out from internal framework structures with WinDbg or similar.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how list itself would help you?

Comment: @OlegBogdanov I hope that items in the list will contain at least location where task is going to resume. But since stack crawler in .NET is already able to construct stack trace across async boundaries - I guess that there's a way to get full stack trace of the deadlocked task chain (my mental reasoning is that if I manage to resolve deadlock with an exception in the topmost task - I will get precisely what I need).

Comment: Have you tried [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998369.aspx) window ? I'm not totally sure its available for dumps though

Comment: @OlegBogdanov it is empty if you open it from memory dump debugging

Comment: It could be a hint that there's no post mortem data of this sort  in the dump  :( User @Stephen Clearly would know.